# Wordpress / Elementor site doesn't load full or correctly

Tags: wordpress, image, loading, elementor

this is the first site I'm building and I used Wordpress with Elementor (free).
During the editing I can see and load all the pages correctly, once I set the maintainance mode off and check for the actual page it doesn't load correctly or full.
Neither on desktop or phone but differently.
This is the site: https://pintoeguglielmiavvocati.it
As you will see it doesn't load the most of the items, but this is how it is supposed to look:
[Editing fase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqgkO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions must contain code or something we can solve. [Please do not link to your site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). There could be anything going on and it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the below file from the path using the Siteground panel.

Path: wp-content/uploads/siteground-optimizer-assets/siteground-optimizer-combined-css-da73c7b494340564d202480a79ab7f1d.css

=>Clear SG cache from the WP admin panel or Siteground Panel and reload the page and check it.

Comment: Thanks bro it worked, do you think this could happen again cause of the Siteground Optimizer plug in? In that case I should clean the cache periodically?